# Java Regex: How to match all patterns including overlapping regex matches?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a String `NNNN`.

The regex is `N+N`.

How to configure the matcher to let it return `NNNN`, `NNN` and `NN` since `NNN` and `NN` also match pattern `N+N`?

Comment: You could find this yourself if you searched for *overlapping regex matches*. Nested is a bit different category.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you, I just don't know what's the jargon to describe my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose your pattern in a lookahead and a capture group:

```
(?=(N+N))
```

The results are in the group 1.

Since the lookahead is a zero-width assertion, characters are not consumed by the pattern and can be "reuse" for the next match (from the next position in the string).

```
N    N    N    N  
x______________^  # first match
     x_________^  # second match
          x____^  # third match
```

`x____^` is the content of the capture group and `x` is the start position.

Comment: Nice Answer! However, would you please tell me how could I find the start and end for each group in Java?

Comment: @spacegoing: `Matcher.start()` and `Matcher.end()`.